# VS 2008 - how can I run a "pre" source control checkin validation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I would like to run a script automatically on a pre source-control checkin but see no option to do. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and, if so, how?

When I say script; I have a executable that validates the a solution file and returns an Environment.Exit code of 0 or 1 for success or fail. It would be really cool if it would then be possible to cancel the checkin based on the result of the executables exit code.

Thank you Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build-in support for canceling the checkin based on the result of the executables exit code. But you can create visual studio add-in for this

All the best...
s